# iphone to connect with bloetooth credit card swipper

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a bluetooth card swiper, i need help to start coding for swipper. i dont find help in sdk and online. is there any other way to user blue tooth device on iphone like credit card swipper.

Thanks and Regards.
Deepak.

Answer (score 1):

The ExternalAccessory framework can communicate with accessories both via the dock connector and via bluetooth. However those bluetooth accessories have to be specifically designed for the iPhone to make use of that capability.

You'll need to apply for the Made For iPod/Works with iPhone programme at http://developer.apple.com/ipod/ and sign the relevant NDAs (and enter into a contractual agreement with Apple for revenue sharing) before you can have access to the technical details you'll need to modify the card reader to work with the iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Your bluetooth device must be MFi verified product to communicate with iOS apps. Otherwise it may only act as A2DP or HID device. Contact your card swiper manufacturer for information of MFi and any SDK for `External Accessory Framework` available.